# fclose Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fclose

I am getting the warning on my pages

> Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource

Using the following code

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
$write = '2';
fwrite($fp, $write);
fclose($fp);
```

**Update code**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['go1']))
{
    $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
    $write = '1';
    $fp1 = fopen('file.php', 'w');
    $write1 = '<br><img src="/1/online.png" style="position:absolute; z-index:-2;" />';
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['go2']))
{

    $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
    $write = '2';
    $fp1 = fopen('file.php', 'w');
    $write1 = '<br><img src="/1/offline.png" style="position:absolute; z-index:-2;" />';
}

fwrite($fp, $write);
fclose($fp);
fwrite($fp1, $write1);
fclose($fp1);

$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
$contents = fread($fp, filesize('data.txt'));
fclose($fp);
if($contents == '1')
    include('file.php');
else if($contents == '2')
    include('file.php');
else
    echo 'Something else...';
```

getting the error on line 27 and line 29
line 27

```
fclose($fp);
```

line29

```
fclose($fp1);
```

Comment: Did you check to make sure the file was opened correctly?

Comment: @Burhan Yes the file is opening and writing the same

Comment: Is there anything else in the script? If there is, try to simulate the same thing with only these lines. Also, make sure 'data.txt' is actually written to and not just some old file from previous experiments :)

Comment: @Vatev I have updated the code,Please advise

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the "if-else" statement (file not opened)... check your code

Answer (score 1):

When your if() condition returnes false, there's no $fp file opened so there's nothing to close. PHP does not understand what file you wanted to close cuz there's nothing opened.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility that springs immediately to mind is that the `fopen` failed for some reason, leaving `$fp` set to `FALSE`.

This could occur, for example, if you weren't allowed to create or overwrite the `data.txt` file (permissions and so forth).

From the `fopen` and `fclose` documentation for PHP (slightly paraphrased):

> The fopen() call returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> The file pointer for fclose() must be valid, and must point to a file *successfully* opened by fopen() or fsockopen().

(my italics). You really should check the return value from `fopen` to make sure it worked before trying to use the file handle.

---

Based on your updated code, you should check that one of those request variables (go1 or go2) is actually set. If neither is, then you will not open the file, but you'll still try to close it.

And, though you *said* it wrote to the file, you might want to confirm that by deleting it before you start a run. You may just be seeing the previous file.

Comment: but the file is opening and writing the same

Comment: You should still check the return code from `fopen` (and `fwrite` by the way) just in case. Permissions are _one_ reason for failure, there could be others. Otherwise please confirm that the code you have posted is _exactly_ what you have (including with no intervening stuff). The reason I ask is that your code is basically the _canonical_ example as per http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php, so it's unlikely it wouldn't work as is.

Comment: @user1561466: there is a code path where you don't open the file but attempt to close it - see the update.

Comment: I have checked the written file and its confirm that the file is opening and desire code is written to it